# ReactJs spread dom element object

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs

I'm trying to merge element object into normal object

```
var el = document.querySelector("mytag");
var data = {...el.dataset};
```

Above works fine in `browser` and `iphone 5` and some other `devices`. But it does not work on `iphone 6 >` — It shows empty object for data.

Does anyone know why its doing this and how I can have it fixed?

Full version of the code

```
var el = document.querySelector("dynamicApiConversionForm");
var data = {...(el.dataset)};

if (data.steps)
    data.steps = data.steps.split(',');

if (el)
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(DynamicApiConversionForm, data), el);
```

Comment: How is this question related to react?

Comment: thats what I thought after posting it lolz, but I was using within react in `ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(DynamicApiConversionForm, data), el);`

Comment: In react, querying directly DOM is not often used since there are many possible traps, since react creates its own DOM like structure and then transfers it (or parts that changed) to real DOM. So there are many places one could slip.

Comment: So how would I replace the above snippet (updated version) and fix it? If you can shade some light on the right direction, I would be very grateful to you. Thanks in advance

Comment: If anyhow possible, I would probably try to reorganize whole approach so that fetching from DOM is not necessary, but I do not know what is the problem app is solving, and if it is possible.  (that is the reason I choose to comment instead offer answer). Sorry!